# Filter Layerlist in Snapping Options Dialog

Tags: pyqgis, snapping, pyqt4

I have some large QGIS-Projects where I would like to filter the layerlist that is used for the advanced snapping options.
Even if there are a lot of layers used in the project I only have to adjust the snapping options for some of these layers.

[image]

I know that I could set the snapping-options programatically for single layers but I need to adjust the snapping options dynamically during my work (snapping mode, tolerance and so on) so this is not an option.

I think I found the item that is used to display the layerlist:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, 'SnappingOption')

st_widget=dlg.findChildren(QStackedWidget)[0]

test= st_widget.children()[2].children()

l_widget= test[1]
l_widget.setVisible(False)
print l_widget
```

But how can I filter this list in order to show only some of my layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found a solution on my yown:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

def filter_snapping_list():
    dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, 'SnappingOption')
    snapping_mode=dlg.findChild(QComboBox).currentText()
    #check that snapping mode is set to "Advanced"

    #if snapping_mode=="Erweitert": #I use the German UI, so it's "Erweitert" and not "Advanced" in my case
    if snapping_mode=="Advanced": #Choice if English UI is used
        print "Snapping Mode ok"   
        st_widget=dlg.findChildren(QStackedWidget)[0]
        test= st_widget.children()[2].children()
        l_widget= test[1]
        root = l_widget.invisibleRootItem()
        child_count = root.childCount()
        for i in range(child_count):
            item = root.child(i)
            url = item.text(1) # text at first (0) column

            # [Name1, Name2] Names of the layer for which the Snapping should be accessible (Case sensitive)
            if item.text(1) in ["AP_LPO","AP_PPO","AX_BAHNVERKEHR"]:
                print "Found: "+url
            else:
                #Hide unwanted Layer from Snapping-Dialog-Layerlist
                item.setHidden(True)
    else:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Set Snapping mode to advanced!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=3)

filter_snapping_list()
```

Before applying the filter: [image]

After applying the filter: [image]

Edit1: Here additionaly a way to interactively select the Layers in the TOC which should be available for the snapping settings:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

filter_List=[]

def filter_snapping_list():
    global filter_List
    print filter_List
    dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, 'SnappingOption')
    snapping_mode=dlg.findChild(QComboBox).currentText()
    #check that snapping mode is set to "Advanced"

    #if snapping_mode=="Erweitert": #I use the German UI, so it's "Erweitert" and not "Advanced" in my case
    if snapping_mode=="Advanced": #Choice if English UI is used
        print "Snapping Mode ok"   
        st_widget=dlg.findChildren(QStackedWidget)[0]
        test= st_widget.children()[2].children()
        l_widget= test[1]
        root = l_widget.invisibleRootItem()
        child_count = root.childCount()
        for i in range(child_count):
            item = root.child(i)
            url = item.text(1) # text at first (0) column

            # [Name1, Name2] Names of the layer for which the Snapping should be accessible (Case sensitive)
            if item.text(1) in filter_List:
                print "Found: "+url
                item.setHidden(False)
            else:
                #Hide unwanted Layer from Snapping-Dialog-Layerlist
                item.setHidden(True)
    else:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Set Snapping mode to advanced!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=3)

def get_filter_layers():
    selectedLayers = iface.legendInterface().selectedLayers()
    global filter_List
    filter_List=[]
    for i in selectedLayers:
        filter_List.append( i.name() )

get_filter_layers()
filter_snapping_list()
```

Only Selected Layers are shown in the Snapping Settings Dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to directly filter the dialog containing all the layer, but maybe this code could be a workaround, assuming that you need to select only some of your layers and to set specified snapping options for them (same options for the selected layers).

I think it should be clearer if you have a look on this code (run it as a script from the **Processing Toolbox**):

```
##Select_Layers=multiple vector

from qgis.core import *

# Get the input files
layers = Select_Layers.split(';')

# Iterate over each selected layer...
for item in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    for layer in layers:
        if item.source() == layer:
            # and set proper snapping options for it
            QgsProject.instance().setSnapSettingsForLayer(item.id(), True, 2, 1, 4, True)
```

With reference to the terms between the parentheses in the last line of the code, following the sequence:

- `item.id()` is the id of your layer (taken from your selection, so don't modify it);
- Available options: `True` (to enable the layer snapping); `False` (to disable the layer snapping);
- Available options: `0` (to vertex); `1` (to segment); `2` (to vertex and segment);
- Available options: `0` (layer units); `1` (pixels); `2` (map units);
- `4` is the tolerance (set it as you want);
- `True`: avoid intersections.

For example, if you have four layers ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd') and you run the code only for the layer 'b':

[image]

you will have:

[image]

as desired. I hope you was looking for something similar to this.

Comment: Thanks for this idea but the users need to be able to change the snapping settings interactively and can't use pyqgis themselves while their work